# VW Mk4 TDI (ALH) – Suggestions for Removing Stuck Water Pump

Tags: vw, jetta, water-pump, tdi

I'm in the middle of replacing a leaking water pump on our 2002 ALH TDI and have finally gotten to the point where I'm trying to remove the old pump. So far no joy...

I got the new pump from DieselGeek and it came with a set of studs that are supposed to act as extractors (you pull the three bolts holding the pump in and replace them with the studs which have a section that is supposed to cut threads in the pump to push it out against the bottom of the bolt holes) unfortunately they don't seem to be developing any "push" – I'm thinking the holes in the current pump may be too large.

Any ideas for what to try? I've tried prying, but it is hard to get enough room to develop any force.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what ended up working for me was to cut a piece of 1x2 lumber (I couldn't fit a bigger piece from above) about 24" long and I braced it against the pump drive cog and pounded on it with a five pound sledge. Once I saw it start to move a bit I crawled under the car (which was up on jack stands with the front wheels, fender skirts, skid plate and side panels removed) and hit the cog again going up using a piece of 2x4 about 12" long.

Did that a couple of times and it dropped right out.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Sometimes the old fashioned methods are the most effective :) Glad you see you were using proper stands too!